# dropped a new fuji x100s

Tags: equipment-damage, fujifilm, maintenance, fujifilm-x100

I just got a new fuji x100s and dropped it on the sidewalk from pocket height (3 feet).

It has some scratches on bottom corners, but appears to be working ok. Is it possible that some internal instruments got damaged or mis-calibrated? is there a way to check this?

**update**

i took a series of photos at day/evening times, and they all look sharp when exported into a computer with large screen. Also the exposure and white balance appear to be working great.

Comment: Taking a photo?

Comment: are you asking if i dropped it taking a photo? nope it was in my pocket when it fell out.

Comment: Im asking if you tried to turn the camera/take a photo, this is what everyone will try to do at first...

Comment: yes, i took some photos and it appears to be working (as mentioned in my question), but i can only preview them in the LCD on the back, so can't be 100% sure if focus is working well. in fact its a new camera so i don't know it well enough to tell if there would be a difference in photo quality.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like you have done very extensive testing yet to see if you can determine if the camera is working as it should on your own. I would try this before sending it in as it may save you the trouble. See:

- [How can I test whether my camera is working after it was dropped?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/41658/how-can-i-test-whether-my-camera-is-working-after-it-was-dropped)
- [What should I look out for when buying a second-hand DSLR body?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/what-should-i-look-out-for-when-buying-a-second-hand-dslr-body)
- [How can I test a new lens to make sure it is operating correctly?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12215/how-can-i-test-a-new-lens-to-make-sure-it-is-operating-correctly)

The last one pertaining to lenses has especially in depth answers to test the focus which seems to be your main concern.

If after the above tests have been exhausted, you either have inconclusive results or just want to be sure, I would send it back to the manufacturer for a cleaning and calibration. They will let you know what may need to be fixed if anything.

Comment: Really this is a duplicate of the first question I linked to...

Comment: most (if not all) of those suggestions are for a camera with interchangeable zoom lens that doesn't apply to the x100s. I updated my question with some of the tests i got to later

Comment: No, they aren't. Can you manually focus? Then you can test focus.