# Could bouncing around in a car trunk damage my DSLR?

Tags: equipment-damage

I'm a new DSLR user, I have a 760D (Rebel T6S) a kit lens (18-55) and a 50mm 1.8. Now, I'm a very careful user (reaaaallly careful with any one of my gadgets) but today I went on a country side car trip and wasn't aware that my camera was in the bag tossed into the car trunk (my family members thought that I would want to take the camera and decided to put it in the car). I only noticed that my camera was there when we arrived at the destination.

It's was a very rough dirt road, and since the bag was in the trunk, it was on a hard surface (it was secure, at least that).

So should I be concerned? I didn't have time to test it but when I do, what things should I look for? Both in the lenses and in the body?

Comment: Did the lens cap stay on the lens? Do you see any obvious damage? I've taken both my Rebel and my 7D in backpacks on planes, through rivers, up mountains, into arenas, and more. It's never been a problem. The only repair I've ever had done was for a loose screw in a lens that caused it to not be able to fully extend.

Comment: Yes. The cap was on the lens... On both lenses. I had the 50 mm mounted on the body. But both the camera and the kit lenses were on a small compartment of the bag, so they were "tight", which means that the lens cap didn't had enough space to giggle.

In the past minutes i took several test shots and everything looks normal. But again, i'm a very beginner photographer, i have no idea on what to look for. lol

Comment: Related: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/59568/can-vibration-damage-my-camera

Comment: And: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/30856/how-to-tell-if-an-impact-to-the-camera-caused-any-damage

Comment: Little risk. I take my cameras regularly on such trips, hundreds of miles, and never had any issues. They can take that.

Comment: Was the bag a proper camera bag or padded?

Comment: Well, it was a normal 40€ camera bad with some padding in all directions. 

Thank you a lot for your answers. I've taken lots of photos since then, specially with the 50mm, and nothing seems of. I guess it's the nervous part of me that went to defcon 1 or 5 or whatever is the most dangerous. lol :D

Answer (score 4):

Don't worry about it. Damage tends to be obvious if it happens, and cameras have to be tough, even entry level ones. My old camera is a 350D (probably 13 years old, still a useful spare). It has been on multiple safaris, in a bag on the floor of the vehicle. It's bounced against my newer camera hung round my neck when I expected to be able to hold them and couldn't. When it fell out of my car and landed on the unpadded bag lid on concrete, the lens died in an obvious way (loose glass rattling around) but the body was fine. If a variety of test shots worked it's not broken.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So far, i haven't noticed any weird things on the photos i've taken since then. They look sharp (specially the ones taken with the 50 mm) and focused. And no noticeable anomalies.